# $|x^2-xy-y^2|=1$ implies that $x=\pm F_{n+1},\; y=\pm F_n$

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

So I've proved that

$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
\implies A^n= 
\begin{pmatrix}
F_{n+1} & F_n\\
F_n & F_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$

for Fibonacci numbers $F_i$.  I'm also asked to show conversely that $|x^2-xy-y^2|=1$ implies that $x=\pm F_{n+1},\; y=\pm F_n$.  So it occurred to me that given

$
\Lambda=
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y\\
y & x-y
\end{pmatrix}, 
$

the determinant of $\Lambda$ is $x^2-xy-y^2$.  If det $\Lambda=\pm 1$, then $\Lambda$ is non-singular.  The inverse is simple enough, and just playing around with stuff I noticed that $\Lambda^{-1}A\Lambda =A$ and so $A^n=\Lambda^{-1}A^n\Lambda$.  However I'm not sure how to proceed from here.    Any hints?

Comment: This is (essentially) an old IMO problem from 1981. You can observe that if $(x,y)$ is a solution with positive integers, then $x>y$, and both $(x+y,x)$ and $(y,x-y)$ are also solutions. These amount to one step forward/backward in the Fibonacci recurrence. Then a simple induction proves that $(F_{n+1},F_n)$ is a solution. Working with the backwards recursion you can show that these are all the solutions (look for the smallest solution). I also think that this has appeared on our site earlier. Because of the IMO-connection it is quite likely that it has appeared in AOPS.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This is from a course in enumeration, and we aren't aloud to use induction in our proofs.  I have to present the answer with a combinatorial argument.  I should have mentioned that.  I can also use generating functions.