# Find all positive integers solutions for $x^2-xy-y^2=1$

Tags: diophantine-equations

> Find all positive integers solutions for the following diophantine equation
> $$x^2-xy-y^2=1$$

**My work so far**

1)$$x^2-xy-y^2-1=0$$
$$D=y^2+4(y^2+1)=5y^2+4=k^2, k \in \mathbb Z$$
2)$$ y^2+xy-x^2+1=0$$
$$D=x^2+4x^2-4=5x^2-4=m^2, m\in \mathbb Z$$

Comment: $$4=(2x-y)^2-5y^2$$

Comment: Well, there are clearly an infinite number of them..My guess is that they have something to do with Fermat-Pell equations.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000045, (x,y)=(A000045(2n+1),A000045(2n))

Comment: Also consider this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1514098/x2-xy-y2-1-implies-that-x-pm-f-n1-y-pm-f-n

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You reached $k^2-5y^2=4$.  To proceed from here, you need the theory of Pell equations.  One way is to consider the LHS which has a factorization in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt5]$.

In $\mathbb Z[\sqrt5]$, the norm is $N[a+b\sqrt5] = a^2-5b^2$, so we are actually seeking elements s.t. $N[z]=4$.  Clearly $z_0=3+\sqrt5$ is a solution, but there are infinite units satisfying $N[u]=1$, so there are a lot more solutions of form $z_0 u^n$.

Case 1: $z_0 = 3+\sqrt5, u=9\pm\sqrt5$
Here $z_n = (3+\sqrt5)(2+\sqrt5)^{2n}=(3+\sqrt5)(9\pm 4\sqrt5)^n$ is always a solution for $(k, \pm y)$.

Case 2: $z_0 = 2, u=9+4 \sqrt5$
Here again $z_n =2(9+ 4\sqrt5)^n$ generates solutions for $(k, y)$.

The first few solutions using 
Case 1 positive branch is $(x, y) = (2, 1), (34, 21), (610, 377), (10946, 6765), (196418, 121393)...$.

Case 1 negative branch is $(5, 3), (89, 55), (1597, 987), ...$

Similarly from Case 2 we have: $(13,8), (233,144), (4181, 2584), ...$

---

P.S. If you prefer the recursion, it is $f(n+2)=18f(n+1)-f(n)$, for both $x_n, y_n$, ...

or a simpler one can be observed from the pattern - all Fibonacci numbers are covered in the form $(y_1, x_1, y_2, x_2, y_3, x_3, ...) = (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...)$..

Comment: But $(5;3), (13,8) -$ solutions of equation

Comment: @Roman83 Tied up in something - will get back soon after I get time to double check what I missed...

Comment: @Roman83 You missed the fact that some of the trivial solutions can also be negative. So the set of trivial solutions is $\{(3,1),(-3,-1),(-3,1),(-1,3)\}$. Also the trivial solutions of $k^2 - 5y^2 = 1$ are $\{(9,4),(-9,-4),(9,-4),(-9,4)\}$. So to find all the solutions you need to check all the combinations

Comment: Think all cases covered now...

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a recent program to do this:

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental_A
2  1
1  1


  3^2 - 5 1^2 = 4

1 x^2 + -1 x y -1 y^2 = 1

Fri Apr 29 10:40:50 PDT 2016

x:  2  y:  1 ratio: 2  seed 
x:  5  y:  3 ratio: 1.666666666666667
x:  13  y:  8 ratio: 1.625
x:  34  y:  21 ratio: 1.619047619047619
x:  89  y:  55 ratio: 1.618181818181818
x:  233  y:  144 ratio: 1.618055555555555
x:  610  y:  377 ratio: 1.618037135278515
x:  1597  y:  987 ratio: 1.618034447821682
x:  4181  y:  2584 ratio: 1.618034055727554
x:  10946  y:  6765 ratio: 1.618033998521803
x:  28657  y:  17711 ratio: 1.618033990175597
x:  75025  y:  46368 ratio: 1.618033988957902
x:  196418  y:  121393 ratio: 1.618033988780243
x:  514229  y:  317811 ratio: 1.618033988754322
x:  1346269  y:  832040 ratio: 1.618033988750541
x:  3524578  y:  2178309 ratio: 1.618033988749989
x:  9227465  y:  5702887 ratio: 1.618033988749908

Fri Apr 29 10:41:10 PDT 2016
2  1
1  1
Inverse of given automorphism of quadratic form:
1  -1
-1  2
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

As you can see, the $x$ values are the odd index Fibonacci numbers, and the $y$ values are the even index Fibonaccis. The formal way to get from one solution $(x,y)$ to the next larger is
$$ (x,y) \mapsto (2x+y, x+y).  $$
As the determinant of the automorphism matrix is $1$ and the trace $3,$ we use Cayley-Hamilton to get separate
$$ x_{n+2} = 3 x_{n+1} - x_n, $$
$$ y_{n+2} = 3 y_{n+1} - y_n. $$

The same information is contained and explained in Conway's Topograph diagram for this quadratic for $x^2 - xy- y^2.$ I drew this picture for my answer at [Solve the following equation for x and y:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132187/solve-the-following-equation-for-x-and-y/1132347#1132347) where it was used for $x^2 - xy - y^2 = 5.$ In today's problem we found $x^2 - xy - y^2 = 1.$

[image]